# Include artifactory hosted swift package from Xcode

Tags: xcode, artifactory, swift-package-manager

I have a swift package hosted in a local repository on a JFrog Artifactory account. I have followed this guide to set it up: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/swift-registry

It does not, however, outline how to add the package to a consuming Xcode app project. Also, my package is not publicly available and therefore requires username/password to access.

I would simply like to consume this package in my Xcode application project. Does anyone know if this possible and how to do it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? In the same boat at the moment. 

Comment: @Baza207 In short: No. I eventually got stuck on this issue: https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/issues/6395. I went with a git repository on bitbucket to host my SPM instead.

Comment: @Baza207 Regarding uploading to Artifactory, I was able to upload by using 1. swift package archive-source on the package and then 2. upload through the Artifactory UI. Uploading using curl did not work out for me.

Comment: Thanks @PKeno. I managed to get uploading to work too with this example https://github.com/spqw/swift-package-registry-demo/blob/main/README.md which works a treat. However same issue for use anywhere other than Swift Packages. For sure seems like a missing feature in Xcode sadly. Thanks for the link, will for sure follow it.